# How to add extra attrs each checkbox CheckBoxSelectMultiple?

Tags: django, python-3.6

How to add extra attrs each checkbox CheckBoxSelectMultiple? Does someone solved this problem? For example:

```
self.form.fields['color__colors'].queryset = Colors.objects.filter(color__product__isnull=False).distinct()
```

I need to add attr "data-color-hex" which value is color object field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just override checkbox form template

```
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" style="background-color: {{ color.color_hex }};" name="{{ widget.name }}"
    {% if widget.value != None %} data-color="{{ color_hex }}"
   value="{{ widget.value|stringformat:'s' }}"
   class="uk-checkbox {% if color.color_hex == "#FFFFFF" %}white{% endif %}"
    {% endif %}
    {% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %} />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add `attr` to the `field` like the following:

```
self.form.fields['field_name'].widget.attrs["attr_name"] = 'attr_value'
```